# Obtaining the velocity of a neutron from its kinetic energy

Tags: kinematics, nuclear-physics, nuclear-engineering

I was told that the velocity of the neutron is calculated using the following formula:

$$v=1.383\times10^6 \sqrt{E}.$$

$E$ is the kinetic energy in $eV$ and $v$ is in $cm\space s^{-1}$

Does this equation hold only for the neutron or is it valid with other particles?

Comment: $$E = \frac{1}{2}mv^2$$

$$v = \sqrt{\frac{2E}{m}} =  \sqrt{\frac{2}{m}}\sqrt{E}$$ For low velocities, the above is true.

Comment: It is *approximately* true for protons, too. But as @YashasSamaga shows that's because the proton has almost the same mass.

Comment: @riccs_0x You're expected to be able to guess a thing like that. The precense of the energy is the clue you should be working from.

Comment: And by 'low velocities', @YashasSamaga means energies well below the rest mass (~900MeV) of a neutron.

Comment: Everyone finds themselves in a classroom where the instructor is expecting more of them than they are used to from time to time. Don't worry that it has happened, just get busy upping your game. It'll make you a better thinker for whatever you end up doing, even if it isn't physics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following derivation is true for small values of $v$.

$$E = \frac{1}{2}mv^2$$

$$v^2 = \frac{2}{m}E$$

$$v = \sqrt{\frac{2}{m}}\sqrt{E} = k\sqrt{E} \tag{1}$$

As your equation accepts $E$ in $eV$ (electron-volts) and gives out the answer in $cm \space s^{-1}$, we'll need to make some adjustments to equation $(1)$.

$$1eV = 1.6\times 10^{-19}J$$

$$E \space eV = E \times 1.6\times 10^{-19}J$$

If we substitute $m$ and $E$ (with the conversion constant) in S.I. units in equation $(1)$, we will get the result in $ms^{-1}$. To convert $ms^{-1}$ to $cm \space s^{-1}$, we'll have to multiply the number by $100$.

$$v = 100\times \sqrt{\frac{2}{m}} \sqrt{E \times 1.6 \times 10^{-19}}$$

$$v = \frac{4 \sqrt{2}\times 10^{-8}}{\sqrt{m}} \sqrt{E} \tag{2}$$

where $v$ is in $cm \space s^{-1}$, $m$ is in $kg$ and $E$ is in $eV$.

---

For a neutron, 
$$m = 1.675\times 10^{-27}\space kg$$

Substituting the above number in equation $(2)$, we get:

$$v = 1.38 \times 10^6\times \sqrt{E} \tag{3}$$

You can find the mass $m$ of different particles and substitute it in equation $(2)$ to obtain the $v-E$ relation.

As the equation depends on the $m$ of the particle, this equation will not work for every particle. The equation for neutron might give answers pretty close to the answers for a proton as the mass of the proton $(1.673\times 10^
{-27} kg)$ is nearly equal to the mass of the neutron.

As a matter of fact, you would obtain the equation $(3)$ for protons as well. The difference in the mass between the two particles is too small to affect the constant $(1.38)$ in the first two decimal places.